# How to add filter (per week) in the sum for distinct value in this query

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx

I found the following sample from internet, it calculates sum `[Measures].[Job Advert Value]` for distinct `[JAP ID].[JAP ID]`.

However, it only shows total sum for everything, and I would like to sum it only for each week.

I tried to add FILTER for `[Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Week].members` that is Time dimension, but does not work.

Below query works without FILTER function.

```
SCOPE([Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Week].members, [Permanent Placement Value].[Value Type Name].&[Vacancies], [Measures].[Job Advert Value] );

    [Measures].[JAP Advert Value] = 
 SUM 
    (
            generate
            (
                [JAP ID].[JAP ID].MEMBERS AS s,
                s.CURRENT *
                TAIL(
                    NonEmpty
                        (
                         [Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Date].members, 
                         (s.CURRENT, [Measures].[Job Advert Value])
                        )
                    )
            )
        , 
        Measures.[Job Advert Value]
    );

END SCOPE;
```

Comment: if you change this line `[Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Date].members` to this `[Time].[Year - Week - Date].CURRENTMEMBER` does it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest trying one of the following:

```
SCOPE([Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Week].members
    , [Permanent Placement Value].[Value Type Name].&[Vacancies]
    , [Measures].[Job Advert Value] );

[Measures].[JAP Advert Value] = 
SUM(
  GENERATE(
    [JAP ID].[JAP ID].MEMBERS AS s
   ,s.CURRENT *
    TAIL(
     NONEMPTY(
       EXISTING [Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Date].MEMBERS
       ,(
         s.CURRENT
        ,[Measures].[Job Advert Value]
        )
      )
    )
  )
,Measures.[Job Advert Value]
);

END SCOPE;
```

or

```
SCOPE([Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Week].members
    , [Permanent Placement Value].[Value Type Name].&[Vacancies]
    , [Measures].[Job Advert Value] );

[Measures].[JAP Advert Value] = 
SUM(
  GENERATE(
    [JAP ID].[JAP ID].MEMBERS AS s
   ,s.CURRENT *
    TAIL(
      NONEMPTY(
       [Time].[Year - Week - Date].CURRENTMEMBER
       ,(
         s.CURRENT
        ,[Measures].[Job Advert Value]
        )
      )
    )
  )
,Measures.[Job Advert Value]
);

END SCOPE;
```

Also I'd suggest experimenting with your scope with the following:

```
SCOPE([Permanent Placement Value].[Value Type Name].&[Vacancies]
, [Measures].[Job Advert Value] );
```

Comment: Hi whytheq, Thanks for your reply. It seems to work with EXISTING. :)

Comment: @JJ0022 glad it helped

Comment: Hi whytheq, Thanks for your reply. It seems to work with EXISTING! :-) However, with EXISTING [Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Date].MEMBERS, the result seems to be doubled. Could it be something with MEMBERS?  I can see that [Time].[Year - Week - Date].[Date].MEMBERS does not contain 'All' members. I am not sure why it becomes doubled.

Comment: it is generating for each member in `s` - so more likely that this has two members `[JAP ID].[JAP ID].MEMBERS`